# How to ignore or replace "carriage return" in informix 4GL

Tags: informix, isql, 4gl

Say I have the following query:

```
insert into myTable values ("TEST 1 
TEST 2")
```

Then I'm selecting the description to output to an excel sheet:

```
select description from myTable
```

Result:

> description  TEST 1
> TEST 2

This will result the output for the single-line description column to be split on 2 separate lines in the .xls output.

How can I resolve this so I get the entire string on 1 line.

Can we loop it through and find the carriage return and replace it? Or?

Thank you.

Comment: Silly question time: if you don't want newlines or carriage returns in the data, why do you insert such characters?

Comment: Right, but I am not the owner of the program where the insert is being done. I'm writing a report pulling information from all over and their inserts are being done from all over as well. For a quicker solution I wanted to first make sure that the report works. Then I can track down the developers of the original programs and research where the inserts are made.

Comment: There's usually a reason — it is worth asking the question, but you have an answer.  'Hysterical raisins', better known perhaps as 'historical reasons', are depressingly commonly the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the "replace" clause, you can do the following:

```
select replace(replace(description,chr(10),' '),chr(13),' ') from myTable
```

- `chr(10)` is ASCII 10, which refers to LF (Line Feed).
- `chr(13)` is ASCII 13, which refers to CR (Carriage Return).